# UIActivityIndicator starting loop after the execution of the process

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to get my UIActivityIndicator start animating when the process of data consumption start downloading. My concern is: how do you get the activity indicator start animating at the same time? I have gone through some solutions here on Stack Overflow, yet I am trying to find some universal solution, since I am utilizing a subclass of UIActivityIndicator. I am not sure if a separate thread can resolve this issue?

I used:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

However, this didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return from the method starting the activity indicator.  The UI (including the activity indicator) updates after an app returns to the main run loop.  Handle any long activities (such as your download) asynchronously with delegates or callbacks, so that the activity indicator can continue to run.  So return from the method that starts your download as well.  Finish later in another method.

Another option is to do the download, or other long process, in another thread.  Operation queues and blocks can be used for this purpose.   Use a performselector on the main thread to update the UI, as an app can't update the UI directly from within a background thread.

Comment: Well the way how I am starting the animation is basically I am calling from a uibutton, but it is being started at my subclass so I have a method called startLoading which starts animating and then return from that method, however its still in the same ibaction to commute some logical transactions. Seams like I need to get out of ibaction to get back to main loop, but how would I be able to ever make this generic then?

Comment: If you have generic sequences, you could refactor them into some helper function, that takes all the differences as parameters to the function.